# how to use multiple request class in rules method (Livewire)

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-livewire

```
protected function rules()
{
    return (new FormRequest)->rules();
}
```

Like above code how to use multiple request classes?

Comment: Livewire is not intended to work with request-classes, because of the nature of how the subsequent API calls are. That said, the rules is just an array of attributes, how you achieve that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

In a technicality, you're simply not supposed to use form requests within Livewire. However, since you're only using the rules from the form request, all you'd need is an [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

```php
protected function rules()
{
    return array_merge(
        (new FormRequest)->rules(),
        (new OtherRequest)->rules(),
    );
}
```

Comment: When I try to work like you said it gives an error **No property found for validation: [0]**

Comment: That sounds like an issue within your form requests. You understand that those form requests don't have access to the input presented by Livewire, right? You can only use "flat" rules, simple rules that don't interact with the input.

Comment: when I use like this it work fine ```protected function rules()
{
    return (new FormRequest)->rules();
}``` but when I use your way ```protected function rules()
{
    return array_merge(
        (new FormRequest)->rules(),
        (new OtherRequest)->rules(),
    );
}``` it give error  **No property found for validation: [0]** means that this is no error in request class. Their must me a different approach to work with multiple request classes in livewire

Comment: Please share your form requests

Comment: To troubleshoot that, the easiest approach is just to `dd()` the result of those merged arrays somewhere and study the output.

Comment: Thank you @Yinci You are right , error was in the request class !!

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function rules(){

    return array_merge(

        (new FormRequest)->rules(),

        (new OtherRequest)->rules(),

    );

}
```

**This works fine if they are no errors in your rules, but cannot work for multiple forms. In multiple forms, clicking on one submit pushes the validation errors on the other form. You can try this on the new method you want to use for validation**

public function updateProfile(FormRequest, $request){

```
$data = $this->validateOnly($request->rules());




 Profile::create($data);
```

}